# Is it possible to add multiple Markdown templates in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, templates

I am building a Laravel application and i am sending mails with Markdown. I have mails that go to the user and mails that go to the admins.

Reading the documentation i can make a new 'theme' with a different css, but i want the layout completely different.

My vendor folder now:

```
vendor > mail > html/text
```

My goal

```
vendor > mail1 > html/text
vendor > mail2 > html/text
```

My config/mail

```
'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('/views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
```

How do i achieve this?

Comment: What's your exact question? Isn't it possible to use that `paths` array? Additionally, please check for proper tagging. To me, this looks like unrelated to Markdown (the formatting syntax to generate HTML markup) itself

Answer (score 1):

The Laravel mailing system is based on components.

The default mail structure uses `@component('mail::message')`, which uses `@component('mail::layout')` -- you can make new ones and reference them.

The only thing the config file does is tells Laravel which CSS to inject by matching the theme name. And it tells Laravel where to look for "mail::" components.

If you want to send a completely different layout, then all you need to do is tell your mailer to use your different layout component.

So you can copy `message.blade.php` to `admin-message.blade.php` and copy `layout.blade.php` to `admin-layout.blade.php` and in your admin mailable, use `@component('mail::admin-message')`.

Comment: Thanks! This is a solution for my problem, although i was looking for a clean way to totally separate them in folders so not all files will be double.

Comment: You can definitely still use a folder structure if you like. I believe the dot-notation would work here (I've not done it that way) - ie: `mail::admin.message` would look in `views/vendor/mail/markdown/admin/` or something along that line.